# How do I demonstrate that a non-linear system has solutions?

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, implicit-function-theorem

I've a question about non-linear systems: I've started to do some exercises on the implicit function, when I've found one that asks me to discuss the existence of solutions $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$ of the following system:

$$\begin{cases} x+e^z+yz\sin(x)=1 \\ ze^z+\sin(xyz)+y^2x=0 \end{cases}$$

How do I proceed? I can't see how implicit functions could help me here...

Comment: Sometimes it helps to try to simplify the problem by assigning one variable a value.  For example, what happens when $x=0$?  It simpliflies of course, so you are no longer considering the fully generality of the problem, but you may be able to find *one* solution.

Comment: The implicit function theorem does not help you in proving the existence of solutions. It gives a local description of the set of solutions under several assumptions, one of which is it being $\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I know, that's why I'm confused, this exercise asks me to find solutions for every $x,y,z\in\unicode{x211D}$, but with the implicit function I find solutions only around a specific point.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no "recipe" to get a solution for arbitrary non-linear problems, here the situation is fairly nice.

Setting $x=0$ in:

$$ \begin{cases} x+e^z+yz\sin(x)=1 \\ ze^z+\sin(xyz)+y^2x=0 \end{cases} $$

gives the simplified problem (since also $\sin x = 0$):

$$ \begin{cases} e^z=1 \\ ze^z=0 \end{cases} $$

This is clearly satisfied when $z=0$ and for any $y$ whatsoever.  Thus we have a line of solutions (the $y$-axis) to which the implicit function theorem may be applied.

---

With marty cohen's further observations all the solutions that lie in any coordinate plane are simply the points in the $y$-axis.  We may then ask if any solutions with only non-zero coordinates exist.

Note that generically the two equations in three unknowns would produce a one-dimensional family of solutions.  This is no doubt a part of the discussion called for in the OP's motivating exercise, that by specifying a nonzero value of one variable we can in principle find how varying that value affects the other variables.

To be more explicit about solving the given non-linear system, the first equation can be "solved" for $y$ in terms of $x$ and $z$:

$$ y = \frac{1 - x - e^z}{z \sin(x)} $$

whenever $z \sin(x) \neq 0$ of course.  Given that $x,z\neq 0$, the only such unaccounted possibilities are when $x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi$.

This expression for $y$ can then be used to eliminate $y$ in the second equation, so that the problem will mostly reduce to solving one equation in the two unknowns $x,z$.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing in hardmath's path,
if we set
$y=0$,

$\begin{cases}
 x+e^z+yz\sin(x)=1 
\\ ze^z+\sin(xyz)+y^2x=0 
\end{cases}
$

becomes
$\begin{cases}
 x+e^z=1 \\ 
ze^z=0 
\end{cases}
$

for which the only solution is
$x=z=0$.

Similarly,
if we set $z=0$,
the equations become

$\begin{cases}
 x+1=1 \\ 
y^2x=0 
\end{cases}
$

for which the only solution is
$x=0$ and
$y$ can be any value.

Comment: Thus the only solutions in any coordinate plane are the points along the $y$-axis.  Since we have two equations in three unknowns, we expect the solutions to form some kind of one-dimensional variety.  This motivates a search for any solutions *not* having zero in any coordinate, and analysis (perhaps involving the implicit function theorem) of what such one-dimensional "trajectories" look like.